# how do I set the "app wide" culture of a blazor serverside app to UK

Tags: c#, blazor, cultureinfo

Ive been trying (without success) to change the default culture in my Blazor serverside app to UK format.  Ive created an extension method on IApplicationBuilder but it doesnt work, dates are always in US format, heres the extension method

```
public static void UseBrowserLocalisation(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        
        var culture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture;
        CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = culture;
        
    }
```

And this is how ive implemented it in the configure method of Startup

```
app.UseBrowserLocalisation();
```

Can anyone see where Im going wrong here ?

**Update
I managed to get it working eventually, I added this code to the Configure method in startup

```
var localizeoptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions()
            .SetDefaultCulture("en-GB")
            .AddSupportedCultures("en-US")
            .AddSupportedUICultures("en-US");
        app.UseRequestLocalization(localizeoptions);
```

Comment: Have you tried setting DefaultThreadCurrentCulture and DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture instead?

Answer (score 0):

First, use the namespace “using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;” in startup.cs file.

Then in “ConfigureServices” method of startup.cs add this code:

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        
        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            var CultureInfo = "en-GB";
            var supportedCultures = new[] { new CultureInfo(CultureInfo) };

            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(CultureInfo);

            options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
        });

    }
```

Configure service for default localization in ConfigureServices then add a middleware in the Configure method of startup.cs like this:

```
app.UseRequestLocalization(app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalization
```